# Image Loading Ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am just playing around with Ionic and Vue 3.

But Images are not loading correctly from the assets folder when I use `ion-img` tag.

Folder Structure:

```
- assets
-- logo.svg
- views
-- Authentication.vue
```

When I load an image with the standard HTML `img` it works but with `ion-img` it doesn't.

```
<ion-row>
      <img src="../assets/logo.svg"/>
      <ion-img src="../assets/logo.svg"></ion-img>
</ion-row>
```

I already tried the following variants for src-path:

```
./assets/logo.svg
../assets/logo.svg
../../assets/logo.svg (Irrational but I tried it too)
~/assets/logo.svg
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Have you tried: /assets/logo.svg.
I believe assets is a folder in the root directory right?

Comment: Inspect the page and look at the `src` attribute (or property) of the `img` inside the `ion-img`. You can also look at whether it fires any [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img#events).

Comment: When I inspect the element the `img` `src` is transformed to /img/logo.843232.svg and the `img` in `ion-img` is not transformed at all

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

[How to reference static assets within vue javascript](http://%3Cion-img%20:src=%22require(%27../assets/logo.svg%27)%22%20/%3E)

In short, you should get what you want doing this:

```
<ion-img :src="require('../assets/logo.svg')" />
```